# c# Use graphics.CopyFromScreen in the same time in 2 threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, screenshot

I would like to do 2 screenshots at the same time. How can I do this? When I made 2 backgroundworkers and each contained the CopyFromScreen method, it throws an error :

> System.ArgumentException: Parametr jest nieprawidłowy.    w
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()    w
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY,
>   Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize,
>   CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)    w
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Point upperLeftSource, Point
>   upperLeftDestination, Size blockRegionSize)    w
>   Screenshoot_z_healem.Form1.backgroundWorker3_DoWork(Object sender,
>   DoWorkEventArgs e)

My code for 2 Backgroundworkers looks :

```
   private void backgroundWorker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // Shot size = screen size
                Size shotSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;

                // the upper left point in the screen to start shot
                // 0,0 to get the shot from upper left point
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(600);
                int y = Convert.ToInt32(600);
                Point upperScreenPoint = new Point(x, y);

                // the upper left point in the image to put the shot
                Point upperDestinationPoint = new Point(0, 0);

                int q = Convert.ToInt32(700) - x;
                int w = Convert.ToInt32(700) - y;
                // create image to get the shot in it
                Bitmap shot1 = new Bitmap(q, w, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

                // new Graphics instance 
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(shot1);

                // get the shot by Graphics class 
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(upperScreenPoint, upperDestinationPoint, shotSize);
                Bitmap b1 = shot;
                shot1.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            };


        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker4_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // Shot size = screen size
                Size shotSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;

                // the upper left point in the screen to start shot
                // 0,0 to get the shot from upper left point
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(600);
                int y = Convert.ToInt32(600);
                Point upperScreenPoint = new Point(x, y);

                // the upper left point in the image to put the shot
                Point upperDestinationPoint = new Point(0, 0);

                int q = Convert.ToInt32(700) - x;
                int w = Convert.ToInt32(700) - y;
                // create image to get the shot in it
                Bitmap shot2 = new Bitmap(q, w, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

                // new Graphics instance 
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(shot2);

                // get the shot by Graphics class 
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(upperScreenPoint, upperDestinationPoint, shotSize);
                Bitmap b2 = shot;
                shot2.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            };

        }
    }
```

Backgroundworkers do the same thing. Get screenshoot of area of screen.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker3.RunWorkerAsync();
        backgroundWorker4.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

What method should i do to make 2 screen in the same time? Maybe i should just start 2 programs and will be without error?
I know i can get the image that i want via crop 1 big image from primary screen ,but  i need to do that that in that way.

Comment: Does it even work to take a screenshot from one backgroundworker??

Comment: Yes it works very well

Comment: The standard reason for "Parameter is invalid" is forgetting to Dispose() the bitmaps you created.  The garbage collector can't keep up with the high rate at which you consume unmanaged memory, the Bitmap object is too small to trigger a collection.

Comment: @HansPassant i edited my code and added dispose to each bitmap and still the same error.

Comment: Nobody is going to believe that is the code you actually tested.  You need to learn how to use the `using` statement.  The Graphics object needs it as well.

Comment: Want all code? I just put here example , not all code :D i know how to use using statements :D

Comment: The problem seems to be with your screen sizes. You are creating a bitmap with the size 100x100 and try to copy the screen with the size `shotSize`. If your screen is bigger then 700*700 this numbers wont match.

Comment: @NtFreX You'are wrong man where do you see i create size 100x100?  I create 600,600,700,700 ...

Comment: @adam You set `x` to `600`; Then `q` to `700 - x`  which is `100`; Then you pass `q` to the `Bitmap` constructor. Same with `y` and `w`.

Comment: Yes you right but ,this does not concern the problem and has no relationship with that. Screens are correct and can set them in picturebox without errors . So takeing screen is 100% correct , you can check yourself if you don't undertstand code. The problem is run it in 2 threads parallel.